# Log all http and https traffic that goes to the router in OSX

Tags: unix, logging, tcpdump, osx-snow-leopard

My router has ip 192.168.0.1. 
How can I log all the traffic it receives under http and https(port 443)?
I think using tcpdump should do the trick but I'm not sure how to run it

Comment: That depends a lot on the router. What kind is it?

Comment: You are not giving us enough information. Is the router your Mac box? A dedicated router? If yes, what kind? Are there other stations in the network that might send data via the router?

Comment: the router is a D-Link DIR-615 . I'd like to log all the PCs traffic to it

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the ethernet hardware address of the router (because traffic sent through it can be recognized by being sent to this link layer address):

```
$ arp -n 192.168.0.1
? (192.168.0.1) at 0:12:34:56:78:9a on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

Then use this address to tell tcpdump what to look for:

```
sudo tcpdump 'ether host 0:12:34:56:78:9a and not host 192.168.0.1 and (port http or https)'
```

Note that the quotes are needed to keep the shell from tripping over the parentheses.  Also, if you leave out the `and not host 192.168.0.1` part, it'll include traffic *to* the router (i.e. it would show you opening the router's web-based config interface) as well as *through* it.  Finally, if you happened to have a DNS or /etc/hosts name defined for 192.168.0.1, you could use tcpdump's gateway primitive (`sudo tcpdump 'gateway somename and (port http or https)'`), but that doesn't work with IP addresses.

Edit: this will only report traffic going through the computer it's running on -- usually just traffic to/from that one computer.  If you want to see traffic through the router from *all* hosts on the local lan, you need to set up some mechanism to have all of those packets sent to your capture computer.  The WireShark documentation has a [good discussion of the options](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet#Switched_Ethernet) for this.